# Check if item is member of list of objects

Tags: python

I'm looking for a clean way to check if an item is member of a list of objects.
Basically this is what I want to do:

```
class Constant:
    def __init__(self,name,value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

list = [Constant('el1',1),Constant('el2',2)]
list2= ['el4','el5','el1']

for item in list2:
    #clean solution for this if clause is needed (I'm aware list.name triggers an error)
    if item in list.name:
        print 'it is a member'
```

So it is important to me that the item matches only on the name, the value has no meaning when searching. I know I can solve this by adding an additional for loop like this:

```
for item in list2:
  for itemConstant in list:
    if item == itemConstant.name:
        print 'it is a member'
```

But I want to be sure there is no better solution than this.

Comment: I can't change the type of item collections I'm using due to restrictions of other key components of the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```
for item in list2:
    if any(item == c.name for c in list):
        print 'it is a member'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since *the value has no meaning* use a set with `in` as strings are hashable and you will have a `0(1)` lookups, storing the names from the instances in a set:

```
st = {Constant('el1',1).name,Constant('el2',2).name}
lst2  = ['el4','el5','el1']

for c in lst2:
   if c in st:
       print('it is a member')
```

Or make lst2 a set:

```
lst = [Constant('el1',1), Constant('el2',2)]
st  = {'el4','el5','el1'}

for c in lst:
   if c.name in st:
       print(c.name)
```

I presume you want exact matches as `"foo" in "foobar"` would be True.

You can also leave the original list as is an create a set from the instance names:

```
lst = [Constant('el1', 1), Constant('el2', 2)]

lst2 = ['el4', 'el5', 'el1']
st = {c.name for c in lst}
for c in lst2:
    if c in st:
        print('it is a member')
```

So you still have an 0(n) solution as it just requires one more pass over your instances lst.

Comment: OP didn't say that `list2` has distinct elements, though.

Comment: @ZiyaoWei, then store a set of `Constant('el1',1).name's`

Comment: Problem is that if I want to use sets I need to convert my lists to sets and convert them back, I need lists to communicate with other parts.

Comment: @demathieu, you don't, you can create a set just for lookups as per the last part of the answer, if you have a large amount of data you will see the cost of building the set will be offset by the efficient lookups, it will be the difference between O(n) and 0(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Make `list2` a *set* and loop over your list of constants to test each against that set. Use the [`any()` callable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to exit early when a match is found:

```
constants = [Constant('el1', 1), Constant('el2',2)]
elements = {'el4', 'el5', 'el1'}

if any(c.name in elements for c in constants):
    print 'is a member'
```

This reduces the problem to *one loop*; membership testing against a set is a O(1) constant time operation on average. The loop is exited early when a match is found, further reducing the number of tests made.

Comment: Problem is that if I want to use sets I need to convert my lists to sets and convert them back, I need lists to communicate with other parts.

Comment: @demathieu: you can easily convert a set back to a list (just use `list(setobject)`. And are you certain that other parts just need something they can loop over rather than a list?